# A Homeomorphism that is not unique even upto Isotopy

Tags: general-topology, geometry, geometric-topology

I'm currently reading the following paper by Richard Skora, entitled *Cantor sets in $S^3$ with simply connected complements* [found here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016686418690060X), and on page 2, just before Theorem 1, it says "the homeomorphism $h \colon S \to S'$ is not unique even upto isotopy".

I was wondering if someone could give me a hint as to why this must be the case; I was initially wondering whether a knot or different linking in one of the genus-2-handlebodies might give rise to homeomorphisms which are not unique?

Comment: Cut $S'$ along its waist and give each component a half twist in opposite directions in a neighbourhood of the waist, keeping the rest of the component fixed, then glue back together along the cut. This is a homeomorphism $h'\colon (S',W')\to (S',W')$ which (I think - you should check) is not isotopic to the identity. Now compose $h'\circ h$ to get a homeomorphism $S\to S'$ which is not isotopic to $h$.

Comment: @DanielRust: Your $h'$ is not isotopic to the identity because its restriction to $\partial S'$ is not isotopic to the identity, which is true because it is a Dehn twist around the essential curve $W'$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks. I knew the operation had a name that I was forgetting. So this is really just saying that some subgroup (those elements represented by homeomorphisms which fix the 'waist') of the mapping class group of the genus-2-handlebody is non-trivial?

Comment: @DanielRust: Yes, in fact it is a rather complicated (and infinite) subgroup.

Comment: Thanks for your replies; would a simpler example to be take a neighbourhood on one side of $W'$, then cut along $W'$, rotate it a whole twist (or $2 \pi$) and glue it back together? I think this would then not be isotopic to the identity?